# How to force a new CNContact into a Local CNContainer?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9, cncontact, cncontactstore

I'm writing an app that stores contact-info fetched through REST and JSON into a container, using CNContactStore. I would like to keep these contacts separate from any other accounts, and only stored locally on the device, but a local store doesn't exist, and I can't find any way to create/activate one?

I'm able to get the default store's ID (as configured on the device, e.g. iCloud), using:

```
let store = CNContactStore()
let containerID = store.defaultContainerIdentifier()
```

...and I can (theoretically) identify a local container like this — if one actually exists:

```
var allContainers = [CNContainer]()
    do {
        allContainers = try store.containersMatchingPredicate(nil)
        for container in allContainers {
            if container.type == CNContainerType.Local {
                print("Local container is: \(container.identifier)")
                break
            }
        }           
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching containers")
    }
```

But no local container exists. Any ideas on how to store my contacts locally, or in a new separate container?

Comment: Once you disable Contacts Sync from iCloud, you function above will return the local container identifier. But I'm guessing that will not solve your use-case. (Cant expect the user to change the iCloud settings again and again)

Comment: Any updates on this? Me too have the same problem.

Comment: When iCloud is enabled, iCloud contacts are used in place of your local contacts. This behaviour is intentional. 

Apple want iCloud contacts to be used in preference to local contacts, so users don't end up with some contacts saved to their device that are not synchronised between devices.

Answer (score 0):

This was possible as follows with the now deprecated AB API, may still work as a workaround:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions( nil, nil );

ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookGetSourceWithRecordID( addressBook, kABSourceTypeLocal );

ABRecordRef contact = ABPersonCreateInSource( source );
```

Comment: Never though of using ABAddressBook as it was already deprecated when we started this project... but I suppose that would otherwise be a better workaround than advising the user to disable/re-enable the contacts-accounts (like e.g. IBM does in their Verse app) :)

Answer (score -1):

The `containersMatchingPredicate(nil)` returns the default container only.

I have a similar problem. If `icloud` has been configured, it would only return the `CNContainerTypeCardDAV` type container else the local container.

Comment: I've sent a request to Apple on this. I noticed that the IBM Verse app (mail) app guides users to disable all Contacts-account, then sync Verse-contacts (to get them local), and then re-enable Contacts-accounts... not pretty.

Comment: This is as designed. When iCloud is enabled, there is no longer a concept of a "local" container

There was a way to trick an iOS device into having both, but it isn't what iOS expects you to do, so is not to be relied on.