# Swift Programmatically Add a Local Contact Container

Tags: swift, cncontactstore, cncontainer

Is there any way to add a contact container to swift? I've looked over CNContainer, but can't seem to find a way. If there isn't a way to do that, does anyone know how to manually add a local container to a device?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587214/how-to-force-a-new-cncontact-into-a-local-cncontainer

Comment: do you need add contact into local container ?

Comment: @a.masri i think he need to add local container to a device .